# Force Dialog LTR in RTL Language

Tags: c++, layout, localization, mfc

I have a resizable dialog in an MFC application that, due to third-party controls, doesn't render correctly RTL (i.e., in Hebrew and Arabic). It is fine LTR. For this reason, I would like to force it to render LTR, even in those problem languages.

I was hoping for a simple global switch for the dialog. If tried removing `WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL` in `OnCreate`, then again at the start of `OnInitDialog`. This makes the dialog itself LTR, but not the child windows.

I can use `EnumChildWindows` to remove the style from the children, however I have numerous 'fixed' controls on the left of my dialog. These are only positioned via the dialog editor and not in `OnSize`. This means the are rendered on the right (seemingly) regardless of `WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL`. I was hoping to avoid having to add variables, and code the size and position of all of these controls in `OnSize` - which would work if I could just get the whole shebang to go LTR!

I'm also investigating `Get/SetProcessDefaultLayout` but so far that is reporting LTR even in RTL conditions - so not that helpful.

In short, is there a way to force a specific dialog to render LTR under RTL conditions without specifically processing the layout of every child control?

Answer (score 2):

Naturally, after spending hours bashing my head against this, as soon as I post a question....I find the answer!

I was trying this:

```
//----------------------------------------------------
BOOL MyDlg::OnNcCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
//----------------------------------------------------
{
    lpCreateStruct->dwExStyle &= ~WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL;
    BOOL res = MyBaseDlg::OnNcCreate(lpCreateStruct);

    return res;
}
```

but what you need is this:

```
//----------------------------------------------------
BOOL MyDlg::OnNcCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
//----------------------------------------------------
{
    BOOL res = MyBaseDlg::OnNcCreate(lpCreateStruct);
    SetWindowLong(m_hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(m_hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) & ~WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL);

    return res;
}
```